# How to not show Title for navigation in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, razor, orchardcms

I am following along on this series of tutorials on building websites with Orchard CMS.  I am working on a template that differs a bit from the one In the tutorial.  The Blog I am referring to is: http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/05/real-world-orchard-cms-part-4-cleaning.html, and specifically section 4.3.

What the blogger is doing is cleaning up the homepage, and adding styles to the titles of the posts.  Where my site differs from the one in the tutorial is that he is using a single navigation (Model.Navigation) and using Orchards default navigation system.  Where I have 2 Navigations defined as widgets and added Menu Widgets.

What is happening is that his example is adding the proper styling to the titles but also forcing the titles to be shown for the navigation (which I have as Model.Navigation1 & 2)

What is the syntax to get it to differentiate my Navigation1 & 2 from the rest of the titles.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Widgets.Models;

@{
    var title = ((IContent)Model.ContentItem).As<WidgetPart>().Title;
    var tag = Tag(Model, "article");
}
@tag.StartElement
    @if(HasText(title) || Model.Header != null)
    {
        <header>
            @if (HasText(title))
            {
                 <h1 class="wiget-title">@title</h1>
            }
            @Display(Model.Header)
        </header>
    }
    @Display(Model.Child)
    @if (Model.Footer != null)
    {
        <footer>
            @Display(Model.Footer)
        </footer>
    }
@tag.EndElement
```

Comment: Which version of Orchard are you using? This article is very old. Did you have a look at the Advanced Menu mdoule? http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu

Comment: I know the article is old, but there isn't much in the way of orchard tutorials, especially as complete as this one

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on how to use the Module.

Comment: Have you installed it? Check this link - http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Installing-and-upgrading-modules

Comment: I have and couldn't figure it out, but that was on day 2 of my use with orchard.  unfortunately for the project I was working on for it I had to move to Drupal, for speed of launch (although I prefer .net in the long term to PHP).  I will work on side projects in Orchard, and try to help with better documentation, and better promote the community.  Thanks for all the help.